How to quote a word in quotes
I want to quote a scholar's use of the term irrealis flavour. So normally I would just say:


XYZ merely says that such constructions have an 'irrealis flavour'.


However, the original scholar actually uses scare quotes around the term irrealis flavour. I would like to preserve the effect of the scare quotes, and do this without quoting a larger section of the sentence that the term occurs in.
How should I achieve this? The following doesn't seem very good:


XYZ merely says that such constructions have an "'irrealis flavour'".



Too simple: "And note that XYZ uses scare quotes herself around the term irrealis flavour, to highlight its blah blah."

@YosefBaskin How peculiar. I thought you'd get that if I didn't have enough spare words to quote a larger part of the original I don't have a spare couple of sentences to riff liberally in an editorial way about the original (as if everybody was in love with the sound of my voice). Can you do better, please?

I am in love with the sound of your voice.

The older question has only one answer with only two upvotes, if anything, the older question should be closed as a duplicate of this one.

You could use [sic] after the quote.

XYZ merely says such constructions have an “irealis flavour” [sic].

Wikipedia says

The Latin adverb sic (/sɪk/; thus, so, and in this manner) inserted after a quotation indicates that the quoted matter has been transcribed or translated as found in the source text, including erroneous, archaic, or unusual spelling, punctuation, and grammar.


To me, this doesn't provide any indication that scare quotes were used, or even that the original author put the word in quotes. It might as well be indicating that the English spelling of "flavour" was in the original, or some other mistake that I'm too stupid to recognise. (Sic is disfavoured or restricted in use by a lot of style guides these days.)

@StuartF that people feel intimidated by "sic" or have not learned (learnt) how to use it, does not bother me.  ‘Sic’ says that the expression was written and punctuated in that manner. There are many old fashioned writing customs that are better abandoned but this is not one of them. There are probably better workarounds, for instance just leaving the scare quotes as they are and adding an explanatory footnote.  Stuart, feel free to post an answer, explaining why "sic" should be avoided and suggest a more contemporary and elegant solution.

I do like 'sic', but I don't know how to make it clear that the 'sic' refers to the punctuation as opposed to the word?

@Araucaria-Him there's no guarantee that the reader will understand whether sic refers to the original-sounding expression, the spelling, the punctuation marks, or a combination of all three. How important is it that the reader is aware that the author used scare quotes? Super important? You could use a footnote, or perhaps add a url link if the document is digital

@Mari-LouA It's kind of important because in the larger paragraph I'm refuting the idea that said person subscribes to the view that the past tense in conditionals has an irrealis meaning.

@Araucaria-Him I see, so it's not trivial... but since I asked, your question's been closed as a duplicate.  If you're fine with that there's no need to reopen but if not, you can cast your first reopen vote, and I'll follow suit. The snag is to convince Laurel to change their mind, her being the mod who closed it.

An unambiguous fashion to do that consists in using just a few words between a pair of parentheses, as did the following author (bold type added).

(The Journal of Criminal Law, Criminology and Police Science 1959 ·)
In the following sentence, the writers state that "permissiveness" (their, not my, quotes!) is not used because of the possibility of suggesting the […]
[…] that someone could explain why "pierced defenses" leave a patient in a "crippled state" (the authors', not my, quotation-marks!).


Yes, this is probably the least expensive way in terms of words. (The italics and exclamation mark would be frowned upon in my field, so that's not the part that I'm agreeing with. It's the: not my quotation marks)

In a now-deleted comment jsw29 answered:

There probably isn't much more to say about this than what you already know: 2 is technically correct for what you are trying to do, but looks awkward. The only ways to remove the awkwardness are to change the sentence so that a larger chunk of XYZ's text is quoted, or to explicitly address the matter by adding something like '. . .  which XYZ himself put in quotes'.



In a now-deleted comment Edwin
Ashworth
answered:

XYZ merely says that such constructions have an 'irrealis flavour' (their scare quotes):

You're using a report structure, not a quotative structure, here.
Using a quote structure:

XYZ merely writes/posits: "Such constructions have an 'irrealis flavour'." (The use of 'say', usually referring to spoken quotes unless context decrees otherwise [CGEL says: ' ...'] can be
misleading here. Cambridge Dictionary lists 'to speak words' first in the list of definitions, so positing that this is the default unless context shows otherwise.)



I think this comment was deleted for a good reason, namely the idea that 'say' usually refers to spoken quotes.

Both CD (by listing first) and as far as I can interpret OED indicate that 'express [a quote] in speech' is the default sense. So according to Grice, other senses should be indicated (eg by context). I've not found an authority negating this.

@Araucaria-Him I myself was the person who deleted the original comment after copying it hither.

@tchrist I see.
